# Detect logged in/out users

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, calculation

*(Sorry for bad English)*

I have two arrays. First is "old" and next is "new".
New array is sended when someone logs in/out to my program's server.

For example old array is {"Thomas", "Eliza"} and new array is only {"Thomas"}. Now I want to find what has been changed (and broadcast this like "Eliza has been logged out")

So from these two arrays I want to get next two like Removed and Added.

Example B: (pseudocode)

```
string[] old = {"Thomas", "Eliza"} 
string[] new = {"Thomas", "Eliza", "Beth"}

string[] added = //magic code
string[] removed = //magic code 2

if (added.length > 0) {
//broadcast logins
}
if (removed.length > 0) {
//broadcast logouts
}
```

I can use Linq, thanks for help!

Comment: `Except` can get you the added users for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
    string[] Old= new string[3]{"Thomas", "Eliza","John"};
    string[] New= new string[3]{"Thomas", "Eliza", "Beth"};
    var intersect = New.Intersect(Old, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray();
    var loggedIn = New.Where(x=> !intersect.Contains(x)).Select(x=>x).ToList();
    var loggedOut = Old.Where(x=> !intersect.Contains(x)).Select(x=>x).ToList();
    foreach(var s in loggedIn)
      Console.WriteLine(s + " has logged in ");
    foreach(var s in loggedOut)
      Console.WriteLine(s + " has logged out ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems silly to broadcast the "User X has logged out" message when the array of users logged in has changed because you would need to compare the two arrays constantly. Messages that a user has logged out would be repeated because you would be keeping a constant copy of "old", filled with registered users and an ever changing "new" that would need to be checked against old.

Let's say that we have the users Brian, Jack, John and Lisa, our arrays would look like this:

```
Users[Brian, Jack, John, Lisa]
LoggedIn[Brian, Jack, John, Lisa]
```

Lisa logs out and we compare LoggedIn to Users by looping through both and find out who's missing in LoggedIn and broadcast.

```
Users[Brian, Jack, John, Lisa]
LoggedIn[Brian, Jack, John]

Broadcast: "Lisa has logged out"
```

Next, Brian logs out and we do the same thing. Loop through both and find out who's missing:

```
Users[Brian, Jack, John, Lisa]
LoggedIn[Jack, John]
```

Because we have to loop through every user, the messages that get broadcasted are:

```
"Brian has logged out"
"Lisa has logged out"
```

The message "Lisa has logged out" has been broadcasted twice because we have to compare arrays and find out who's missing. This is a bad way of handling this kind of notification because you'll be creating duplicates every single time you compare.

Instead, consider creating a method that handles when a user logs out and is called from a button click:

```
private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogOut(user);
}

private void LogOut(string username)
{
    //Remove username from LoggedIn array
    //Broadcast: username + " has logged out."
}
```

This way, you much more easily manage who's logged in because you don't have to use loops to compare arrays of Users and LoggedIn.

Comment: No, I got an event with new array then I want to compare them (broadcast informations to log) and replace old array by new... so nothing will be duplicated. I don't want to compare them in `while (true) {...}`